# VerifySignature Problem in JAVA

Tags: java

I have implemented a sample code to generate Hash and Sign and Verify the Signature as follows:
But when iam trying to verify the Signature, its throwing me false .it is not able to verify the Signature.

Am I following the correct procedure .Please do suggest

The actual scenario i need is i want to calculate the hash of a file ,sign the hash and decrypt the signature, so i can get the hash which can be verified with the original hash.

Can u please suggest me the APIS to Use and if possible a sample program to do that.

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, SignatureException{

        KeyPairGenerator signkeygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");  
        signkeygen.initialize(2048);//The argument specifies the length of the key in bits
        KeyPair signkey = signkeygen.generateKeyPair();
        PublicKey sign_publicKey = signkey.getPublic();
        PrivateKey sign_privateKey = signkey.getPrivate();

        String test = "hai";

        Signature mysign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        mysign.update(test.getBytes());
        byte[] byteSignedData = mysign.sign();
        Signature vSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        vSign.initVerify(sign_publicKey); 
        vSign.update(byteSignedData);

        boolean signStatus = vSign.verify(byteSignedData);
        System.out.println(signStatus);
        ...
```

Comment: You never tell `Signature` to use `signkey` or `sign_privateKey`? What key are you signing with?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you need to initialize a signingobject to specify that you are signing with your private key. As of now, you are verifying with the public key, but not signing with the private which will throw you a false when trying to verify.

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, SignatureException{

    KeyPairGenerator signkeygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");  
    signkeygen.initialize(2048);//The argument specifies the length of the key in bits
    KeyPair signkey = signkeygen.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey sign_publicKey = signkey.getPublic();
    PrivateKey sign_privateKey = signkey.getPrivate();



    Signature mysign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    mysign.initSign(sign_privateKey);  //Added this line
    byte[] byteSignedData = mysign.sign();
    Signature vSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    vSign.initVerify(sign_publicKey); 


    boolean signStatus = vSign.verify(byteSignedData);
    System.out.println(signStatus);
```

This should return true. Also, when trying to find out which part of the code is faulty, it's not a good idea to `throw` all of the exceptions. Better to catch them and have each one generate a different `println`. This way you can tell what part of the algorithm that is faulty